# Create a custom route in ASP.Net Core that can pass a subdomain as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

Been wrapped around the axle on this one, while there are some questions that are close, they either are different enough (addressing multi-tenancy, URL rewriting, etc), or are not answered.  I would like to create a custom route in ASP.Net Core that takes the subdomain (if any) and passes it to the controller as a parameter.

The closest thing I found was ([here](http://www.mikeminded.net/tutorials/webdevelopment/3-mapping-subdomains-to-areas-in-asp-net-core-mvc)), but I couldn't make it work, not sure what needs to be passed into a constructor that isn't described, but seems to be needed by the base MvcRouteHandler class.

For example, since a normal route might look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/home/index/3
```

Goes to the controller as

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to create a custom route that takes a URL like

```
http://somesubdomain.example.com/home/index/3
```

and turn it into

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string subdomain, string id)
    {
        // "somesubdomain" is passed into the subdomain parameter.
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks, I've dug through more routing stuff than I know what to do with and custom routing is still pretty opaque to me.  Thanks!

EDIT: I know that in each call I can probably look at the request, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.  That's my fallback, though...

ANOTHER EDIT: [Here's another example of what I want to do, only not in Core.](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/using-subdomains-in-aspnet-mvc-DX)  I'm trying to figure out how to make this 'Core'.

Comment: domain or Subdomain aren't part of the route. You'd have two options though, getting this data from the HttpRequest headers (from `X-Forwarded-For` when behind an reverse proxy such as IIS or nginx) inside the action or write an middleware which extracts this data and place it in `HttpContext.Items` and get it from there. I'm pretty sure the multi-tenancy questions you refer provide exact this (the middleware/`HttpContext.Items` option)

Comment: I guess my question is if I can 'make' them part of the route.  I think that I can just grab the URL from the context, I think, but it seems cleaner to get it as part of the route, if possible.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do it via routes, though using model binder it may be possible, i.e. similar to `public ActionResult Index([FromHeader(Name = "x-forwarded-for")]string subdomain, string id)` or you create your own modelbinder + attribute to handle both cases (behind proxy and internetfacing, i.e. when using weblistener)

Comment: You should consider @Tseng advice ad go for the `HttpContext.Items` route. You could then create an extension method for the `Controller` class that extracts directly the subdomain from `HttpContext.Items`. Strictly speaking, the sub-domain is not part of the route.